# Regular expression of unicode characters on string

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

I'm working in C# doing some OCR work and have extracted the text I need to work with.  Now I need to parse a line using Regular Expressions.

```
string checkNum;
string routingNum;
string accountNum;
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\u9288\d+\u9288");
Match match = regEx.Match(numbers);
if (match.Success)
    checkNum = match.Value.Remove(0, 1).Remove(match.Value.Length - 1, 1);
regEx = new Regex(@"\u9286\d{9}\u9286");
match = regEx.Match(numbers);
if(match.Success)
    routingNum = match.Value.Remove(0, 1).Remove(match.Value.Length - 1, 1);
regEx = new Regex(@"\d{10}\u9288");
match = regEx.Match(numbers);
if (match.Success)
    accountNum = match.Value.Remove(match.Value.Length - 1, 1);
```

The problem is that the string contains the necessary Unicode characters when I do a `.ToCharArray()` and inspect the contents of the string, but it never seems to recognize the Unicode characters when I parse the string looking for them.  I thought strings in C# were Unicode by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was using the decimal values instead of the hex code
In other words instead of using `\u9288 and \u9286` I should have been using `\u2448 and \u2446`  http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x2440

Thanks guys for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: You should accept this answer to keep the thread from getting automatically revived every few months.  And use the `regex` tag instead of variants like 'regularexpressions'--it's the one regex specialists look for (though it turned out this wasn't really a regex question after all).

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
match.Value.Remove(0, 1).Remove(match.Value.Length - 1, 1);
```

causes an exception because the resulting length from the first `Remove` is smaller than the original `match.Value.Length`.

I suggest you use groups to extract the value. Ex:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\u9288(\d+)\u9288");
Match match = regEx.Match(numbers);
if (match.Success)
    checkNum = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

With that, I can extract the values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

String in .NET are [UTF-16 encoded](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html).

Additionally, Regex engines don't match against Unicode characters, but against Unicode code points.  See [this post](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).