# Regex function not working for one illegal character

Tags: c#

I have a problem regarding illegal character usage in file name, under Windows OS.
   I have the following function, which should replace any illegal characters with underscore character.
   But, for some reason, when my string to be replaced is something like `"ABC_test\/:*?"<>|_Jan2016_ABC"`, my function does not replace the backslash character and the final string is `"ABC_test\_________Jan2016_ABC"`.
  Could you please show me what am I doing wrong, because I had expected that after my function was used, no more illegal character should've been present.
   My function is:

```
public static String ReplaceIllegalPathCharacters(String path, String replacement = "_")
{
    string pattern = "[\\~#%&*{}//:<>?|\"-]";
    Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);
    string final = Regex.Replace(regEx.Replace(path, replacement), @"\s+", " ");     
    return final;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: I think you have unicode characters.  See following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835100/regular-expression-of-unicode-characters-on-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to double-escape your backslashes - once for C#, and once for RegEx:

```
string pattern = "[\\\\~#%&*{}//:<>?|\"-]";
```

Code I used to test:

```
void Main()
{
    var stringToReplace = "ABC_test\\/:*?\"<>|_Jan2016_ABC";
    string pattern = "[\\\\~#%&*{}//:<>?|\"-]";
    Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);
    var final = regEx.Replace(stringToReplace, "_");
    Console.WriteLine(final);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively could have used `@` to make it a verbatim string, but then the double quote would have needed to be escaped by another double quote instead of a backslash.  `@"[\\~#%&*{}//:<>?|""-]"`